# openfiledialog results in file is being used by another process

Tags: c#

I would like use C# to upload multiple files to google drive

this is my upload button function

```
private  void bt_upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Filedialog_init();


        DialogResult check_upload = MessageBox.Show("Want to upload these files ?", "Upload", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);

        if (check_upload == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
            {
                UploadFilesDrive(service, result[i], filePath[i], Datatype[i]);
                tx_state.AppendText(result[i] + "Upload Done");
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my Filedialog_init function

```
private static void Filedialog_init()
    {
        Stream myStream = null;
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

        openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
        openFileDialog.Filter = "bin files (*.bin)|*.bin|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        openFileDialog.FilterIndex = 1;
        openFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;
        openFileDialog.Multiselect = false;

        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string filename = null;
            string _datatype = null;
            try
            {
                if ((myStream = openFileDialog.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                    foreach (String file in openFileDialog.FileNames)
                    {
                        filename = Path.GetFileName(file);
                        result.Add(filename);
                        // only show the name of file

                        Datatype.Add(_datatype);
                    }
                    filePath = openFileDialog.FileNames;
                    Datatype.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
                }

                openFileDialog.Dispose();


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Upload Cancel");
    }
```

I can upload the file successfully by assigning the filename and its datatype and path directly

But when I used openfiledialog,it went wrong with "my file is being used by another process"

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Where is the code which opens the file dialog and gives the selected files. Because in that code somewhere you are locking the file access.

Comment: I have tried to use opfiledialog.Dispose()  but it didn't work

Comment: This line `(myStream = openFileDialog.OpenFile()` is still holding lock on file. Try using stream with `using` so that it will dispose the stream as well as lock. Instead do it like `using(Stream myStream = openFileDialog.OpenFile()){ your code here...}`

Answer (score 1):

Issue lies in your code here,

`(myStream = openFileDialog.OpenFile())` This line is keeping lock on the file because your `myStream` does not get `disposed`. you need to `dispose` the stream as soon as you are done with it.

So try with `using` as it will `dispose` the stream as soon as your end using line gets executed. More details on [using](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx).

you can try as below,

```
using(Stream myStream = openFileDialog.OpenFile())
{
    //Your code here...
}
```

Comment: If this fixed your issue please accept this answer so question an be closed.

Comment: where do i put the `Dispose` ? outside or inside `using()` ! , im still getting the same issue of ( The process cannot access the file 'filename.jpg' because it is being used by another process.'
) happen whatever i try to do `File.Copy(imgToCopy, newImageName, true);` , my code is about selecting an image and copy that image to my folder, the new inserted image should have the same unique name of the previous existed image cause im binded that image with specific Shop-items and the image name contain the code bar of that item ..

Comment: @RAMM-HDR you don't need to put and Dispose anywhere. When the `using` curly bracket for end `}` executes it takes care of calling the `Dispose` method for you.